# Accessing Sqlite3 via php not working?

Tags: 11.10, php, sqlite

my local web server on one machine running Ubuntu 11.04 works fine using php5 to access sqlite3 - however on a new machine running Ubuntu 11.10 the same code, same structure, does not work at all - even though phpinfo() indicates all modules are enabled.

Any idea's on how to solve this issue?

phpinfo() on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine indicates PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3 but the newer Ubuntu 11.10 only supports PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.2 ?

Why has it gone back to Ubuntu3.2?

The php code seems to be able open the database file ok, but fails when accessing a Sqlite query in the code below?

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sysconfig');
$data = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE_NUM);
```

The variable $data returns null (however it returns data on Ubuntu 11.04 - ok)

frank

Comment: It has not actually „gone back”. The version number is higher (`5.3.6` vs. `5.3.5`). The part you are referring to is a minor Ubuntu-specific version (`13ubuntu3` subversion `2`). See: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/php5/+changelog

Answer (score 1):

You're executing the query without checking whether its return value is sane. You may get clues as to why this is failing by looking at the return value from this:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sysconfig');
```

Remember that `$result` will be FALSE if the query didn't execute successfully. So after that line you can do:

```
if (!$result) {
  echo($db->lastErrorMsg());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've installed the `php5-sqlite` package.